# Whitelisting of IP in GCP using cloud function not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-api

I am writing a cloud function which gets trigger from slack with an IP and then we whitelist the IP in GCP firewall.
because GCP firewall dont appeand so we have to get the IP and then appear a new IP to and then update it .

I am facing below error

`Error updating firewall rule: FirewallsClient.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'`

I tried a lot to fix this but I am getting one or the other error. so not sure how to fix this, due to lack of understanding about the coding as well.

my code

```
def updateSecurityGroupRule(ip):
    project_id = 'development-404511'
    firewall_rule_name = 'bastion-host-ssh'

    client = compute_v1.FirewallsClient()

    try:
        request = client.get(project=project_id, firewall=firewall_rule_name)
        current_firewall_rule = request
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving current firewall rule: {e}")
        return False

    if isinstance(current_firewall_rule, compute_v1.Firewall) and hasattr(current_firewall_rule, 'source_ranges'):
        # Assuming there is at least one source range in the list
        current_ip_range = current_firewall_rule.source_ranges[0] if current_firewall_rule.source_ranges else None
    else:
        print(f"Unexpected response from client.get(): {current_firewall_rule}")
        return False

    new_source_ranges = [current_ip_range, f'{ip}/32']

    firewall_update_mask = FieldMask(paths=['source_ranges'])
    firewall_update_request = compute_v1.Firewall(
        name=firewall_rule_name,
        source_ranges=new_source_ranges
    )

    print(f"Updating firewall rule with new source ranges: {new_source_ranges}")

    try:
        client.update(project=project_id, firewall=firewall_rule_name, body=firewall_update_request, updateMask=firewall_update_mask)
        print("Firewall rule updated successfully.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error updating firewall rule: {e}")
        return False
def updateSecurityGroupRule(ip):
    project_id = 'project-12345'
    firewall_rule_name = 'firewall-name'

    client = compute_v1.FirewallsClient()

    try:
        request = client.get(project=project_id, firewall=firewall_rule_name)
        current_firewall_rule = request
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving current firewall rule: {e}")
        return False

    if isinstance(current_firewall_rule, compute_v1.Firewall) and hasattr(current_firewall_rule, 'source_ranges'):
        # Assuming there is at least one source range in the list
        current_ip_range = current_firewall_rule.source_ranges[0] if current_firewall_rule.source_ranges else None
    else:
        print(f"Unexpected response from client.get(): {current_firewall_rule}")
        return False

    new_source_ranges = [current_ip_range, f'{ip}/32']

    firewall_update_mask = FieldMask(paths=['source_ranges'])
    firewall_update_request = compute_v1.Firewall(
        name=firewall_rule_name,
        source_ranges=new_source_ranges
    )

    print(f"Updating firewall rule with new source ranges: {new_source_ranges}")

    try:
        client.update(project=project_id, firewall=firewall_rule_name, body=firewall_update_request, updateMask=firewall_update_mask)
        print("Firewall rule updated successfully.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error updating firewall rule: {e}")
        return False
```

while I run it and watch logs I see that script works until here
`print(f"Updating firewall rule with new source ranges: {new_source_ranges}")`

it gets the IP from firewall and adds new IP to it, later it is not updating the firewall back

can someone tell me what is wrong here and is there any better way I can do to update a firewall with ip

Comment: FYI: The VPC Firewall does not control traffic to Cloud Functions. You would need to add a Google Cloud load balancer + Cloud Armor + NEG.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think their context can lead to this confusion but they use the CF to manage the firewall rule only and not to control traffic to the CF.

Comment: @WaseemMir You're not using the correct parameters for the  `client.update()` method. Please read the documentation first https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.firewalls.FirewallsClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_firewalls_FirewallsClient_update You'll notice there's nothing like `body` in the parameters but `request`

Comment: @Puteri - Thank you - I misread the question/problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @Puteri I went through the doc I see request is expected and I tried to modify my code to 
`client.update(project=project_id, firewall=firewall_rule_name, request=firewall_update_request)`
but I am getting this error
`Error occurred: If the `request` argument is set, then none of the individual field arguments should be set. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to above is as below
This will get the IP addresses from your firewall, append the new IP that we pass to it, and the update the firewall with the new range.
I hope this will help any

```
def updateSecurityGroupRule(ip):
    client = compute_v1.FirewallsClient()

    request = compute_v1.GetFirewallRequest(
        firewall="<firewall_name>",
        project="<project_id>",
    )

    response = client.get(request=request)
    current_ips = [ip_range for ip_range in response.source_ranges]

    current_ips.append(f'{ip}/32')

    firewall_resource = compute_v1.Firewall(source_ranges=current_ips)

    request = compute_v1.PatchFirewallRequest(
        firewall="<firewall_name>",
        project="<project_id>",
        firewall_resource=firewall_resource
    )

    response = client.patch(request=request)

    print(response)
```